# I'm trying to find the duplicates in two different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which is simple:

```
Select product_code, ID1, ID2 from product_list
```

But I have a problem

`product_code` has one unique code only, and `ID1` and `ID2` as well for the product_code, so one distinct product,
1 distinct ID1 and 1 distinct ID2 for the product,

but when I extract the list, some times I notice that the ID1 that is showing for product_code X is also showing for product_code Y ID2 or the vice-versa, is anyway for me with a query to detect this?

Thank you very much

Comment: can you be more clearer?

Comment: what exactly trying to do. give examples with code please

Comment: can u please make a SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Why don't you use `UNIQUE` constraints on the columns that should only contain distinct values?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_list
WHERE product_code = ID1 OR product_code = ID2 OR (ID1 = ID2 AND ID1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Added a NULL check, but probably not needed.

```
SELECT *
FROM product_list a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM product_list b
              WHERE a.product_code = b.ID1 OR a.product_code = b.ID2
              OR a.ID1 = b.ID2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood correctly, there are some values in ID1 field that show up also in ID2 field, but for a different product_code.

```
Select p1.product_code, p1.ID1, p1.ID2, p2.product_code, p2.ID1, p2.ID2
from product_list p1, product_list p2
where p1.ID1 = p2.ID2 or p1.ID2 = p2.ID1
```

Comment: Why the down vote? If something's wrong, please explain (so I can learn too, thanks). This should be just an old-format self join (oracle).

Comment: tech.. I guess you are joining between them, in his case you have to find the duplicate , and joinin alone wont be enough .. thats my opinion

Comment: It's only one table, it's to see if there are duplicates eanX that appear in eanY for different product_codes. because all codes, product_code, ean1, ean2 must be unique.

Comment: product code ean1 ean2
A 110 240
B 34 110
C 300 352
D 200 900
Product_code A,B should flagged

Comment: That is exactly what my query does: it shows a table containing, for every row, the codes, ID1 and ID2 for the duplicates; in your example it would show two rows:  A 110 240 B 34 110, and B 34 110 A 110 240.

Comment: if you want a query that shows all the rows, AND an additional column that identifies the duplicates, then use: Select p.product_code, 
        p.ID1, 
        p.ID2,
        (select 1 from product_list q where p.id1=q.id2 or p.id2=q.id1 ) as Duplicate
from product_list p;

Comment: @Moudiz: joining alone is enough to find all the duplicates (and only them): I've tested it on my oracle DB; you could possibly not like that there will be two rows for every duplication, since the query will find both A,B and B,A. That could be fine tuned, but seemed to me more than what was asked; it is the same as doing an inner join as this: Select p1.product_code, p1.ID1, p1.ID2, p2.product_code, p2.ID1, p2.ID2
from product_list p1
inner join product_list p2 on p1.ID1 = p2.ID2 or p1.ID2 = p2.ID1;

Comment: I'll try your's Tech, I just to find the product_code that have duplicates.

Comment: I tried this query and put distinct, when I put distinct I get this Statement 1 is not valid. ORA-00936: missing expression, when I take it works, any idea why? did the same in another query I have and gives the same error.

Comment: May you copy here your query ? (the one that gives you the error)